# Magento Translation via Ajax

Tags: ajax, magento, translate

I have a little problem with translation mechanism in Magento. 
If I call translate mechanism from phtml template like this

`<li class="landline"><span class="value"><?php echo Mage::helper('ssg_rates')->__("Landline") ?></span></li>`

I get translated value from csv file for example "Vaste Lijn" and this is expected output, however when I do the same in block and get data back via AJAX, like this:

1. in controller I create block and call method to output html
2. the method outputs something like this:
   `echo '<li class="landline"><span class="value">'.Mage::helper("ssg_rates")->__("Landline").'</span></li>';`
3. data returned to phtml via Ajax:
   `{{{Vaste lijn}}{{Vaste lijn}}{{Landline}}{{Ssg_Rates}}}`

Why is that? Why it isn't only translated value like in the phtml template?
Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by translation inline for frontend turned on in admin. Disabling it solved the problem.